# Load page directly to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, pageload

When I load a page with a hash tag in the URL, the page loads and then jumps to the anchor tag. Is there any way to prevent this "jump", either by loading the page directly to the anchor tag or at least making the scrolling smooth?

I see this problem in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.

Comment: In case you are linking internally (meaning within a page) you can add an eventhandler to achieve smooth scrolling. But if the user enters a link like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Elements directly i doubt that you can control how the browser jumps to the anchor `#Elements`.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: I am not talking about linking internally. However, the wikipedia page loads directly to the anchor (or at least does not have any visible jumps).

Comment: Hi @dmr. There's no way around the page jumping. Some pages will appear to jump less due to how it's loaded, but the behavior for linking to a section via a hash tag is standard across browsers. For example, even wikipedia has a visible jump for me. You can augment this behavior using jquery to animate the scroll (so it's smoother), or minimize the jump by improving the load time of your page overall (to allow the browser to jump to that section faster, rather than sitting there while it gets ready)..

Comment: I just had an idea. If your page has no anchor or id with the name of the anchor you might be able to smooth scroll by adding the anchor to the dom-tree dynmically after page load.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still experiencing the jumping issue, you could something with jQuery:

```
//Use a RegEx pattern to search for an id, if present
var pattern = new RegExp('\#(.*)');
var id = pattern.exec(window.location)[0].replace('#','');
//Prevent the browser's default behavior of jumping to the id
document.location = '#';
//When the page finishes loading, smoothly scroll to the specified content
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(id != "") {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top,
        }, 650);
    }
});
```

Note that this will only work once per page load.

Comment: great solution. The , after 'offset().top' gave me an "unexpected ','" message though.

Comment: also you should be aware, that this works not on webkit browsers. for those you need to use 'body' instead of 'html'.

Comment: Good catch! Calling `animate` on the `<html>` element seems to work in Chrome (v.32) and Firefox (v.27), but fails in Safari (v.7). I've updated the code to use a `body` selector.

Comment: body will not work with firefox afaik ;).
So you'll have to make an if statement there where you get the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem still preserves with Firefox in XSL and XML files, but already not with HTML. I solve it with this work-about:

```
<script>
var pattern = new RegExp('\#(.*)');
var id = pattern.exec(window.location)[0].replace('#','');
var id2 = pattern.exec(window.location)[0];

function gotoanchor() {
    if ( (typeof id2) != "undefined") {
        document.location=id2;
        alert("We are at the anchor "+id);
    }
}
</script>

</head> <!-- in the head section -->
<body onload="gotoanchor();">
```