# Linking to an anchor on another page lands in the wrong place (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, jquery-waypoints

I have a long page with different divs, with each div containing quite a lot of content. This content is hidden when you land on the page, then is expanded once you reach the heading for each section, either by clicking the link to the anchor or by scrolling. I'm using jQuery Waypoints to do this.

This all works fine whilst on this page. My issue is that if linking to one of these anchors from another page, some of the Waypoints are firing whilst scrolling, increasing the height of the page and so you end up in the wrong place.

**This only appears to happen in Firefox** - Chrome and IE land at the anchor in the correct place with only the correct Waypoint being fired.

I have an example at http://jennoefur.co.uk/test/page1.html. If you go 'Page 2' in the navigation then go to 'Section 6' you should see the problem.

Apologies if this turns out to be a duplicate in some way, I've been searching and searching and can't find an answer or solution. Many thanks for any help, this is the first question I've asked so any guidance on where I may have gone wrong would also be appreciated!

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq-sticky-anything.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="myWaypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('nav').stickThis();

    });

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

<nav id="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="#section5">Section 5</a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="#section6">Section 6</a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="section1">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>This is the introduction section</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <p>
        tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="section2">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap openDiv">
        <h2>Subheading</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <h2>Subheading</h2>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <h2>Subheading</h2>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <h2>Subheading</h2>
        <p>tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="section3">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap openDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <p>
        tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="section4">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>Section 4</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap openDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <p>
        tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="section5">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>TSection 5</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap openDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <p>
        tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="section6">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>Section 6</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap openDiv">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <p>
        tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="section7">

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>This is the closing section</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut aliquam sagittis erat eu tempor. Integer eget dictum felis, nec auctor sem. Ut eu tellus elementum magna rhoncus tristique. Vivamus suscipit lacinia dolor eget dapibus. Suspendisse vestibulum orci hendrerit lectus faucibus, quis faucibus purus aliquam. Donec non ligula eget ante cursus consequat. In ultrices, turpis eget tincidunt facilisis, risus orci sollicitudin odio, a auctor turpis mauris ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Quisque quis lectus vestibulum eros suscipit sollicitudin id auctor nulla. Praesent est lacus, bibendum at vulputate sed, elementum a felis. Donec neque magna, maximus a tempor condimentum, eleifend rutrum odio. Curabitur tincidunt mi eros, quis porttitor nunc porttitor at. Nam eu sapien vel justo commodo interdum at et dolor. Vestibulum eleifend ex justo, non pharetra purus rutrum non. Nam elementum mauris eu dignissim accumsan. Ut eget purus libero. Nunc eget nibh tincidunt, vulputate nisl vel, mollis elit. Aenean laoreet leo eu tincidunt semper. Vivamus sit amet quam malesuada, blandit risus eu, auctor risus. Aliquam porta porttitor facilisis. Maecenas egestas augue justo, eu consequat justo molestie quis. Praesent enim purus, venenatis ac purus vitae, rutrum sagittis augue. Cras imperdiet massa eu condimentum vulputate.</p>
        <p>Fusce venenatis libero a odio ullamcorper elementum. Praesent fermentum ipsum sed felis tincidunt vehicula. Quisque pretium nisl ut massa ultricies, vel dignissim nibh condimentum. Cras ullamcorper neque vel velit scelerisque, et eleifend dolor commodo. Quisque ultricies commodo urna, in viverra ipsum hendrerit aliquet. Vestibulum lacinia gravida odio. Maecenas suscipit tempus risus, condimentum ultricies nunc suscipit quis. Nulla sit amet egestas leo. Aenean eget sapien eu quam elementum pretium dignissim in erat.</p>
        <p>Aliquam vehicula vel ante in commodo. Phasellus semper purus at semper cursus. Duis euismod, sem a vehicula volutpat, nisi nisi pretium turpis, sit amet laoreet orci lacus eget sem. Sed mi dolor, tristique lacinia viverra at, congue ac ex. Duis tincidunt bibendum fringilla. Vestibulum condimentum semper orci. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin ut hendrerit sapien. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis velit purus, aliquet at dignissim in, vestibulum quis sem. Maecenas pharetra maximus risus, nec rhoncus elit bibendum quis. Quisque eleifend scelerisque eros, quis rhoncus ipsum auctor vitae. Nullam magna felis, ornare non leo eu, sodales gravida est. In placerat mauris suscipit tortor accumsan, eu blandit quam sagittis. Phasellus vitae eros eu nisi blandit faucibus. Donec turpis leo, dictum at lacus vel, malesuada luctus libero.</p>
        <p>
        tiam semper justo vitae sapien dapibus efficitur id ut nibh. Sed ut risus odio. Curabitur cursus, nisl ac sollicitudin faucibus, sem enim bibendum tellus, quis lobortis justo arcu non tellus. Vestibulum luctus mi sed est ornare, ac lacinia arcu iaculis. Praesent sed dolor neque. Donec maximus non sem et pulvinar. Quisque ac est eros.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sectionHeading">
        <h1>Footer area</h1>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    background: #666;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    width: 987px;
    margin:auto;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2em;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    }

.sectionHeading {
    background: #666;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5em 0;
    margin: 5em 0;
}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 400%;
    width: 987px;
    margin:auto;
}

.wrap {
    width: 987px;
    margin: auto;
}

.openDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS (for Waypoints):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#section2').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('#section2 .openDiv').slideDown(800, function() {
          Waypoint.refreshAll()
        })
    },{
        offset:80,
        continuous: false
    });


    $('#section3').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('#section3 .openDiv').slideDown(800, function() {
          Waypoint.refreshAll()
        })
    },{
        offset:80,
        continuous: false
    });

    $('#section4').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('#section4 .openDiv').slideDown(800, function() {
          Waypoint.refreshAll()
        })
    },{
        offset:80,
        continuous: false
    });

    $('#section5').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('#section5 .openDiv').slideDown(800, function() {
          Waypoint.refreshAll()
        })
    },{
        offset:80,
        continuous: false
    });

    $('#section6').waypoint(function(direction) {
        $('#section6 .openDiv').slideDown(800, function() {
          Waypoint.refreshAll()
        })
    },{
        offset:80,
        continuous: false
    });


});
```

Comment: Can you paste your souce code so that we can help you debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution based on a comment here - [Load page directly to anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709638/load-page-directly-to-anchor-tag)

Though the above question is not about my specific problem, dynamically adding the IDs for the anchors to the H1 elements resolved the issue I was having.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div.section1 h1').attr('id', 'section1');
    $('div.section2 h1').attr('id', 'section2');
    $('div.section3 h1').attr('id', 'section3');
    $('div.section4 h1').attr('id', 'section4');
    $('div.section5 h1').attr('id', 'section5');
    $('div.section5 h1').attr('id', 'section6');

});
```

The resolved example can be seen here - http://jennoefur.co.uk/test/solved/page1.html